# How can I set up a local mail server and forward external email to another?

Tags: email, postfix, redhat, email-server, dovecot

I would like to set up an email server, using Redhat 7.6, let's call it `mail.domain.tld`. The box is realm-joined to that domain. I want to create email addresses for domain users, for example `fred@mail.domain.tld`, (note that I do want the `mail` hostname to be there, because `fred@domain.tld` is already in use by the domain).

I want this server to handle all email for domain users, and forward any emails that are bound for other domains (Gmail for example) to a separate email server, let's call it `big-mail.domain.tld`. This separate server already exists and is configured.

I wish the emails themselves to be stored on `mail.domain.tld`, and users can access them remotely from other boxes with Thunderbird via imap and smtp.

Is such an arrangement even possible? Is it possible using Postfix and Dovecot? I have been trying to follow many tutorials, but I am unfamiliar with the exact terminology to look for, and my use case seems to be somewhat unusual. This is the way I want it to work, because `big-mail.domain.tld` is not under my control, nor is the Active Directory domain controller itself.

EDIT: I forgot to say, I want the users to be able to authenticate with the mail server using their domain credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad to answer in our Q&A format!

The steps that are needed are roughly:

1. Configure the server to support Active Directory authentication / integration. That is already a topic in itself with several options on how to achieve that: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/index
2. Once that works configure Postfix to accept incoming mail for your domain and to allow authenticated users to *relay* (send) email using your postfix server. See http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html
   Configure postfix to use a [`relayhost`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost) to not send outgoing messages directly over the internet to their recipients, but to hand them over to next hop (smarthost, mail relay, outgoing SMTP server) for subsequent delivery.
3. Install dovecot so that users can login using IMAP and/or POP3. Since your system is already integrated with AD by now, you probably don't need to create virtual users you can probably suffice by using "pam" authentication.

Don't forget to get an TLS certificate and secure your services with that, you don't want your users to send passwords to your services in clear-text!

Comment: As for the first point, that's already taken care of. I don't understand how to configure Postfix/Dovecot to work with `fred@mail.domain.tld` rather than `fred@domain.tld`. Are you aware of any more in-depth tutorials than I was able to find? As for TLS, that's taken care of too :)